# Convert Date Format with Regex / Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, date

I have date data in below format

2020-10-07 05:21:15.

I want to convert it into Wed,7 Oct'20 -05:21pm.

I tried with regex

```
(new Date(2020-10-07 05:21:15)).toString().replace(/\S+\s(\S+)\s(\d+)\s(\d+)\s.*/,'$1 $2,$3')
```

But im getting output `Oct7,2020,`

Can anyone help me out with javascript or regex to format it.

Comment: `(new Date('2020-10-07 05:21:15')).toString().replace(/\S+\s(\S+)\s(\d+)\s(\d+)\s.*/,'$1 $2,$3')` resolves to `Oct 07,2020` for me

Comment: use moment js for all your date time needs

Comment: You can get something close with this: `new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', {weekday: 'short', year: '2-digit', month: 'short', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', hour12: true}).format(new Date())`  But it's not your precise format.  If you need that, then look to building it yourself from the constituent parts.

Comment: Please do not use the built–in parser, particularly for unsupported formats, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results). In Safari at least, `new Date('2020-10-07 05:21:15')` produces an invalid date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
const date = new Date();

// First option

const time = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', }).format(date);
const dayWord = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { weekday: 'short' }).format(date);
const dayNumber = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { day: 'numeric' }).format(date);
const month = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { month: 'short' }).format(date);
const year = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { year: '2-digit' }).format(date);
console.log(`${dayWord},${dayNumber} ${month}'${year} -${time}`);

// Second option with format to parts method

const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {
  year: '2-digit',
  day: 'numeric',
  month: 'short',
  weekday: 'short',
  hour: '2-digit', 
  minute: '2-digit'
}).formatToParts(date);

var customDateString = `${formatter[0].value},${formatter[4].value} ${formatter[2].value}'${formatter[6].value} -${formatter[8].value}:${formatter[10].value}${formatter[12].value.toLowerCase()}`;

console.log(customDateString);
```

Comment: How can i get Time along with this ? like  Wed,7 Oct'20 - 05:21pm.  time in am and pm format  @svyatis.Iviv

Comment: You could shorten that and make it hugely more efficient using a single instance of *Intl.DateTimeFormat* and the [*formatToParts* method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts) to get the parts.

Comment: @rajrajaji I've updated answer with time

Comment: also updated with format to parts method option as @RobG mentioned